# Not able to tweet image on twitter in Android

Tags: android, image, twitter, uri, twitterkit

I'm trying to tweet an image on twitter from the SD card. Also tried to tweet from image URL, but the image not showing on composer.

Below is my code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String path = destination.getPath();
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination.getAbsolutePath());
    //Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(path);


    String body = "…Check it out for yourself !";
    TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
            .text(body)
            .image(bmpUri);

    builder.show();
```

I have gone through available solutions but none of them helped. Please help me to know why an image is not tweeting.

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.